# Random number from a range without a certain number in the middle of the range

Tags: objective-c, random, int

I'm generating a number from 0 to 11 randomly like this:

```
int n = arc4random() % 12;
```

But, I'd like to not get 5 or 6 as output. How can I do that?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(12)` instead of `arc4random() % 12` avoids the modulo bias.

Comment: FYI - `arc4random() % 12` gives you results in the range 0 - 11, not 0 - 12.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Careful with your edit. The OP might really want 0 - 12 but mistakenly used `% 12` instead of `% 13`. You're making a big assumption with your edit.

Comment: Your general point is taken, @rmaddy, but I've edited to match the answers, especially the accepted answer. I'd also suggest that a future reader with the same base problem will have a different set of numbers e's interested in -- that's not the important part of the question, nor was it what was asked about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have such a constraint, make it explicit in your code:

```
int n;
do {
    n = arc4random() % 12;
} while (n == 5 || n == 6); //retry if encountered one of unallowable values
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
int n = arc4random_uniform(10);
if (n >= 5) n += 2;
```

Comment: This is the much better answer. Though you should be using `arc4random_uniform`.